# How display:block effects on transition:opacity?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have two divs. One is shown and other is hidden(using display:none).
When i click on the first div it should slowly disappear (made with transition:opacity), then using javascript's setTimeout i make it display:none and at that time put the second div display:block and add him class (which make him visible with transition:opacity).
The question is: why the first div has the desired effect (slowly disappears) and the second div just immediately shown after that (the transition effect doesn't work in this case).

HTML

```
<body style="border:1px solid black">   
    <div class="square red show" ></div>
    <div class="square blue" style="display:none"></div>
</body>
```

Css

```
.square{
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
.square.show{
    opacity:1;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
.red{
    background-color:red;
}
.blue{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Js

```
$('.red').click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('show');
        setTimeout((function(p){return function(){
            $(p).css('display', 'none');
            $('.blue').css('display', 'block').addClass('show');
        }})(this), 1000); 
    });
```

Example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/y7cX2/
Thanks.

Comment: Does this helps `$('.blue').show(500);`

Answer (score 0):

instead of `css('display','block')` you should write `fadeIn(1000)`..

Check the solution now :

http://jsfiddle.net/y7cX2/1/

Comment: It might be browser issue as I am using IE8 browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.red').click(function(){
        $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 'slow', function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $('.blue').animate({opacity: 1}, 'slow', function(){
                  $(this).show();
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: No explanation at all?

Comment: @hicurin , thanks, i know this solution, but it doesn't help me. The main idea why i didn't use it: i need make all effects using maximum css as possible (showing and hiding), because all js-code will most probably be changed. And i just need to emulate the situation that there is red div, and it disappears and at its place comes blue div and it is slowly shown. there is one more example jsfiddle.net/y7cX2/6/  and here again blue div is shown immediately. So may be my question should be how to slowly show div after it appears in DOM?